# Issue with document.cookie: Works in localhost but Returns Empty on Web Hosting

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cookies

I've been searching lots and lots of sources but does not seem like anything describes my case.

I am currently trying to develop a website (ReactJS) and a back-end (NodeJS w/ Express). Let's say they are accessible at `example.com` and `example.com/api` respectively on production, and then `localhost` and `localhost:3030` on development. The cookies are set by the API.

Entering `alert(document.cookie)` into my browser's console on my local machine outputs my non-HTTPOnly cookies. However, when I tried this on my web hosting, it only returns an empty alert box, which indicates that `document.cookie` is an empty string `""`. This was tested on Opera, Firefox and Chrome.

I also have already tried unsetting HTTPOnly and secure flag for my session cookies from my Node app but this too is not written into the alert output.

Does anyone here know why this happens and/or how to make this work? Thanks!

EDIT: Here's how I set my cookie on the NodeJS

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.cookie("My-Cookie", random());
    next();
})
```

EDIT2: I guess this is an issue with how CORS actually work. But I still don't get why my localhost version works even though it's also CORS.

Comment: So you want to access the cookie on `example.com` which you set/created on `localhost`?

Comment: I want to read the cookie on `example.com` set by `example.com/api` but does not work. On the other hand, I can output `document.cookie` on `localhost` which is set by `localhost:3030`

Comment: So basically your source code is working when run locally (`localhost`) but isn't working on a public domain name. Possible you should update your question and include some relevant source code like creating the cookie and trying to access the cookie? Thank you.

Comment: To access the cookie, I tried `alert(document.cookie)` in the console as I had described in my post. I have put my cookie generator in the post, though in my code it's a dynamically generated one.

Comment: @NewToJS Silly me. The cookie was set for `www.example.com` and not `example.com`. Opened my page with the `www` solved it. But I still want to know how to make this also work without the `www` or the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this issue is regarding the Set-Cookie domain. First, my cookie was set for `www.example.com` while I open `example.com` in my browser. Second, I fixed this problem by specifying `{domain}` option on ALL my cookie settings including the cookie generator like so:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.cookie("My-Cookie", random(), { domain: '.example.com' });
    next();
});
```

Now I can open either `www.example.com` or `example.com` and `document.cookie` returns the cookie values as intended.

Hope this helps anyone out there who are not aware of this limitation.